# EDI X12-3060 : POA 855 file structure

Tags: edi

I haven't any sample file for `POA` with multiple transaction set. As i am exploring about `POA` where file must contains Multiple `PO` and each `PO` contains multiple `PoLines` along with `Ack`.

Lets say i have `2 PO` and each po have 2 `PoLines` along with Acknowledgment. I have created the POA file as what my understanding after reading the EDI tutorials, but confused whether file structure is correct or not.

```
ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*1697978        *01*1234567        *060110*0937*U*00401*000000834*0*P*>?
GS*PR*1697978*1234567*060110*0937*24*X*003060?

ST*855*000000001?    // For PO-1
BAK*00*AE*200601100645*060110?
N1*ST**15*1234567?
PO1*48899*1*EA*14.95*SR*IB*0060654570*B6*MANNING BRENNAN?
PID*F****Reflections for Ragamuffi?
ACK*AC*1*EA****IB*0060654570*ZZ*00?
N1*ST**15*1234567?
PO1*48899*2*EA*14.95*SR*IB*0060654571*B6*MANNING BRENNAN?
PID*F****Reflections for Ragamuffi?
ACK*AC*2*EA****IB*0060654571*ZZ*00?
CTT*2*3?
SE*12*000000001?

ST*855*000000002?   // for PO-2
BAK*00*AE*200601100646*060110?
N1*ST**15*1234567?
PO1*48900*2*EA*14.95*SR*IB*0060654575*B6*MANNING BRENNAM?
PID*F****Reflections for Ragamufi?
ACK*AC*2*EA****IB*0060654575*ZZ*00?
N1*ST**15*1234567?
PO1*48900*2*EA*14.95*SR*IB*0060654576*B6*MANNING BRENNAM?
PID*F****Reflections for Ragamufi?
ACK*AC*2*EA****IB*0060654576*ZZ*00?
CTT*2*4?
SE*12*000000002?

GE*1*24?
IEA*1*000000834?
```

should `ST-SE` be repeated for each PO Acknowledgment ?

Comment: The ? is a terrible segment delimiter.  You should consider changing it to a ~ or something less likely to appear in your data.

Comment: Yes @Andrew you are right. I'll change the delimiter after discussion with my client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the ST/SE segments are nested just like you have in the example. each encloses a single 855. the GS/GE segments are also nested correctly in your example.

Comment: thanks DOn, one more thing i wanted to know about `GE[01]` value. e.g. in my example there are 2 nested `ST-SE` segments but both are of type 855 therefore i have mentioned the value `1` for `GE[01]`, is it correct ?

Comment: It should be GE*2*24, you actually have 2 transactions

Comment: Two groups, actually.  ISA / IEA = interchange. GS / GE = group. ST / SE = transaction set (document).  Download EDI Notepad from Liaison for free to validate your syntax.